# Men sweat, but women glisten. What's the equivalent for a woman for snoring?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, colloquialisms

Colloquially, we say that men sweat, but women glisten.  Is there an equivalent word for describing when women snore?

Comment: *Serenade*......?

Comment: "Gently burble"?

Comment: Maybe *murmuring*?

Comment: Men perspire, women glow, and horses sweat.

Comment: Women snore, men go lay on the couch.

Comment: For a couple of years I was working on an application to detect sleep apnea.  As a part of the research and testing I listened for hours to recordings of people snoring.  Women snore just as often as men, if not quite as loudly.  Sometimes a snore is just a snore.

Comment: The female equivalent for *snoring*, in any case, would be an *argument*.

Comment: Breathe heavily

Comment: @JamesMcLeod - You beat me to it, but you really should provide a reference. Unless you thought it up all by yourself. Actually, it's "Horses sweat, men perspire, Miss Hayworth glows."

Comment: I was unsure of the order, but you have the correct quotation I was thinking of.

Comment: Who the heck says this colloquial expression? Never heard it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about "purr?"  That seems to me to be in the same neighborhood as "glisten."

Comment: Picking this as best answer based on my wife's advice. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a girlfriend who referred to her "soft sussurations," so perhaps "sussurate," which is defined as "make a whispering or rustling sound."

Answer (score 2):

Wife: I was awakened by your snoring last night so I turned on the music.

Husband: Me too! Two nights ago I was awakened by your pharyngeal rhapsody so I had to turn on the music to match its rhythm.

Answer (score 2):

A soft exhalation could be called *whiffling*.

*Whiffle* has this definition on [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whiffle):

> to emit or produce a light whistling or puffing sound

Here are a couple of examples of the adjectival form of the word used in the book [*Apple Blossom Time*:](https://books.google.com/books?id=iimRBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=whiffling+in+her+sleep&source=bl&ots=7-OEKXyGa8&sig=WGr2VeFXIYWR_dCnk1aj_Qki7OU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC94X76PPKAhXDQCYKHRwhBd4Q6AEIHTAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> By now I could distinguish Pansy's little, whiffling breaths, polite even in her sleep , across the room.

and the book [*Catla and the Vikings:*](https://books.google.com/books?id=_3p0xZSntC4C&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=whiffling+sleep&source=bl&ots=bPpDcOwd72&sig=riw6h_Usz-O3y_ZRNJp0MMmUboI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyluTj6vPKAhVKJCYKHQOpDZg4ChDoAQguMAU#v=onepage&q=whiffling%20sleep&f=false)

> She longed for the noises of her family when they slept around her: Bega's wheezy sighs, Mother's whiffling nose sounds and Father's snuffling indrawn breaths.

Answer (score 0):

As snoring is more often a male problem and women are compelled to endure it we could perhaps say:
Men snore, women listen.

Comment: I thought "treetops glisten and children listen".

Comment: Yes, but only when there's sleigh bells in the snow.

Answer (score 0):

I could stay awake
as you heave your breathing
From a mile where you are ululating
While you purr away resonating

I could spend my life in your beats forever
I could stay lost in these moments of thunder
Every moment spent wishing you for moments of halleluyer

I just wanna close my eyes
I just wanna fall asleep
Cause you'd wake me baby
And I don't wanna miss a wink

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o4kvBI5A98